# How to use LINQ to return the result as Dictionary<string,string> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ. I want to query the files in a folder and return the result as Dictionary.Here is my code

```
var queryResult = (from d in directoryInfo.GetFiles()
                   where d.Name.EndsWith(suffix)
                   select new Dictionary<string, string>
                   {
                       {d.Name,""},
                   });
```

But it seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx) returns an array of [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

It's not clear from your question what you want to have as the Dictionary key and what you want to have as the value.  If you want the Name as both, you could do

```
var queryResult = 
    (from d in directoryInfo.GetFiles()
     where d.Name.EndsWith(suffix) 
     select d).ToDictionary(d=>d.Name, d=>d.Name);
```

That's a fairly meaningless dictionary in that the keys and values are the same.

If you do want to retain the FileInfo for each file, you can instead do this (gives you a `Dictionary<string, FileInfo>`):

```
var queryResult = 
    (from d in directoryInfo.GetFiles()
     where d.Name.EndsWith(suffix) 
     select d).ToDictionary(k=>k.Name, v=>v);
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps. BTW, is there any other way to create dictionary rather than calling the ToDictionary() method?